# thirdweb contract is not installing

Tags: http-status-code-404, smartcontracts, thirdweb

I'm getting an error when I try to install contract using command:
npx thirdweb@latest create --contract

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusCode')
at packageJson (file:///C:/Users/parth/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/86fd6f984ad48a35/node_modules/package-json/index.js:71:22)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async latestVersion (file:///C:/Users/parth/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/86fd6f984ad48a35/node_modules/latest-version/index.js:4:20)
at async UpdateNotifier.fetchInfo (file:///C:/Users/parth/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/86fd6f984ad48a35/node_modules/update-notifier/update-notifier.js:119:18)
at async C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\thirdweb\dist\cli\index.js:431:488
at async Object.callback (C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\thirdweb\dist\cli\index.js:431:424)
at async Command.parseAsync (C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:935:5)
at async xm (C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\thirdweb\dist\cli\index.js:432:6610)

Answer (score 0):

yes there is some problem in latest cli

use this

```
npx thirdweb@0.9.13 create --contract
```